# How to get the decision tree built at an iteration of the Ada boosting package in R?

Tags: r, printing, boosting

I have built a boosting model with 50 decision trees using the "ada" package in R. How can I print the decision tree built at a iteration of "ada"?

I can use the "print" function to display the detail of a "rpart" object, is there any similar function to print the decision trees built in an "ada" object?

Thank you very much!

My sample code is like below:

```
    library(ada)
    data("soldat")
    model <- ada(y ~ .
               , data=soldat
               , loss="e"
               , type="discrete"
               , iter=50
               , control=rpart.control(cp=-1, maxdepth=2))
```

Comment: Can you show a bit of code, a reproducible example perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trees are stored in the list `model$model$trees`
These are `rpart` objects so you can use `print`, `plot` etc., just as when calling `rpart`.

So, for instance to plot the 5th tree:

```
plot(model$model$trees[[5]])
text(model$model$trees[[5]])
```